# SQL command that ignores the first record returned

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that displays comments on a blog based on date. I would like to ignore the first one and display all the rest, something I can't do correctly.

My code so far is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT comment_post_ID, comment_date_gmt, comment_content
   FROM $wpdb->comments 
   WHERE comment_post_ID = {$thePostID}
   ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC 
   LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your limit clause to:

```
   LIMIT 1, 5
```

That means start at the 1th row (0-indexed), and return up to 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT comment_post_ID, comment_date_gmt, comment_content
FROM $wpdb->comments     WHERE comment_post_ID = {$thePostID}
ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC
LIMIT 1, 5
```

ignore first LIMIT 1, how_many